# find the number from the array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

How I can use the  **FIND()** method ?
Here my code.

```
    public static void find_marks(int value)
    {

        int v = value;
        int pos = Array.Find(arr, v);
        if (pos > -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found the number");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Not found the number");
        }

    }
```

Comment: what's the actual problem?

Comment: `int pos = Array.Find(arr, n => n == value);`

Comment: or `bool found = arr.Any(n => n == value);`

Answer (score 1):

I think first you must input array parameter like this:

```
public static void find_marks(int value,int[] arr)
```

You can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.find?view=netframework-4.7.2)

It will describe **Array.Find**

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer